# Searching a list of long strings for a substring and then printing out the next 4 characters

Tags: python, string, list, substring

thanks for reading my question. I will be working through this as we speak and will update the question if I find a solution. Although I fear this may be a bit too advanced for my skillset so I'd appreciate any help!

I have a list of strings, each displaying an error message.

`'Error: Customer (ABC 111) has an activation error'`

`'Error: Customer (ABC 112) has an activation error'`

For each *string* in this list of *strings* I'd like to find the *substring* 'ABC' and then print out the following *four* characters which are corresponding to the ID number.

`OUT: ' 111', ' 112'`

Now I know how to find a substring in a list of strings, but printing the following characters is confusing me.

I will update as I work through the code or until some coding legend helps me out!

Thanks!!

EDIT: Adding MRE and final code below:

Essentially the data was initially provided in an excel file with two headers which was converted to a dataframe in Pandas.

| CONT_ID | ERROR_DESC |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Error: Customer (ABC 111) has an activation error |
| 124 | Error: Customer (ABC 112) has an activation error |

etc.

I needed to iterate over the **ERROR_DESC** column to select the **CUSTOMER_ID** for each row. In the real world the data was a bit more complex, with different codes predating the ID and I also needed another substring from the strings. But for the MRE I will use ABC as the constant.

My final MRE code is below.

```py
cust_id = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   desc = row['ERROR_DESC']
   
   i = desc.index('ABC')
   id_num = desc[i+4:1+7]
   cust_id.append(id_num)
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module

Comment: Would you be able to post a minimum reproducible example/sample code?

Comment: Hey Joshua, thanks for that module. I'll check it out! Yeah let me post a code sample, basically all I have right now (you folks are fast!) is setting up an itertuple operation on the dataframe to get the list of strings I'd like to search from the column they are stored in.

Comment: `[a[a.index("ABC"):][3:7] for a in list_of_strings]`

Comment: If you're working with a dataframe e.g. from `pandas`, there are definitely ways to do this without using an (arguably slow/inefficient) `for` loop.

Comment: It is a pandas example but with only 200-ish records in this instance! I have edited the post to include the MRE and sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of `ABC` and find it on the string:

```py
a = 'Error: Customer (ABC 111) has an activation error'
i = a.index("ABC")
num = a[i+4:i+7] -> '111'
```

Comment: Great, thanks Pedro! I'll try this out and repost all of the code below so if someone has this issue in the future they can see! Also, will accept your answer in 8 minutes when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work from, I'll ask you modify this appropriately to fit your usecase:

```py
import re

#setup
list_of_strings = ['Error: Customer (ABC 111) has an activation error',
                   'Error: Customer (ABC 112) has an activation error',
                  ]
pattern = r'(?<=ABC )(\d{3})'

#the thing you want
customer_ids = [int(cust_id.group(0)) for long_string in list_of_strings\
     if (cust_id:=re.search(pattern,long_string))]

#produces
print(customer_ids)

[Out]: [111, 112]
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex solution Josh, I will incorporate this module into future regex issues!